# Http proxy with https target

Tags: node.js, proxy, node-http-proxy

I'm trying to create my own proxy server in NodeJs with the library `node-http-proxy` the problem is that I want to create a http proxy server that will have the possibility to forward the request to a https target (ex. https://google.com).

I know it's possible, because there is already a library that does this called: [proxy-chain](https://github.com/apifytech/proxy-chain)

When I try to request a https target with `node-http-proxy` I get an error: `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`.

It also states in the documentation that I need to add a PKCS12 client certificate, but the `proxy-chain` does not do this.

Is there a way I can replicate the `proxy-chain` library with the `node-http-proxy` library?

This is my code at the moment:

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  // You can define here your custom logic to handle the request
  // and then proxy the request.
  proxy.web(req, res, {
    target: {
        hostname: 'github.com',
        port: 433,
        protocol: 'https',
    },
    secure: false,
    changeOrigin: true
  });
});

console.log("listening on port 5050")
server.listen(5050);
```

Comment: Do you really have `433` as the destination port for proxied requests?  It should be `443`.

Comment: Hi, It was a typo in my example code. In my project I do use 443.